# runtime classpath using manifest.mf classpath

Tags: java, ant, build, manifest.mf

i built an ear using ant and the its compiling fine. however when i deploy i get the noclassdeffound error in the weblogic server logs. so i added the libraries(jars) in server startup script i.e the server java classpath it works fine.

Please help me how to resolve this runtime classpath issue using ant build. i assume adding classpath in manifest.mf file will help. so far my build.xml is:

Please advice

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="xxx APP Check" default="all" basedir=".">


<target name="init">
<property name="software.version" value="1.0"/>
<property name="user.name" value="usrnme"/>
<property name="dirs.base" value="${basedir}"/>
<property name="classdir" value="${dirs.base}/build/src"/>
<property name="src" value="${dirs.base}/src"/>
<property name="mf" value="${dirs.base}/src/META-INF"/>
<property name="jar" value="${dirs.base}/build/jar"/>
<property name="web" value="${dirs.base}/web"/>
<property name="deploymentdescription" value="${dirs.base}/build/deploymentdescriptors"/>

<property name="warFile" value="xxxappchk.war"/>
<property name="earFile" value="xxxxappchk.ear"/>


<property name="earDir" value="${dirs.base}/build/ear"/>
<property name="warDir" value="${dirs.base}/build/war"/>
<property name="srcDir" value="${dirs.base}/build/src"/>


<!-- Create Web-inf and classes directories -->
<mkdir dir="${warDir}/WEB-INF"/>
<mkdir dir="${warDir}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
<mkdir dir="${warDir}/WEB-INF"/>
<mkdir dir="${warDir}/WEB-INF/lib"/>
<mkdir dir="${warDir}/WEB-INF/classes"/>

<!-- Create Meta-inf and classes directories -->
<mkdir dir="${warDir}/META-INF"/>
<mkdir dir="${earDir}/META-INF"/>


</target>

<!-- Main target -->
<target name="all" depends="init,build,buildWar,buildEar,clean"/>


<!-- Compile Java Files and store in /build/src directory -->
<target name="build" >
<path id="3rdparty.jar.path">
       <fileset dir="${jar}">
       <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>

</path>
<javac srcdir="${src}" includeantruntime="false" destdir="${classdir}" debug="true" includes="**/*.java" >
<classpath>
        <path refid="3rdparty.jar.path"/>
</classpath>
</javac>
</target>

<!-- Create the War File -->
<target name="buildWar" depends="init">
<copy todir="${warDir}/WEB-INF/classes">
<fileset dir="${classdir}" includes="**/*.class" /> 
</copy>

<jar destfile="${warDir}/WEB-INF/lib/xxxx-appcheck.jar"
      basedir="${warDir}/WEB-INF/classes"
/>
<echo message="Hyperion appcheck jar created."/>

<copy todir="${warDir}/WEB-INF/classes/com/ca/xxxx_appcheck">
<fileset dir="${src}" includes="**/*.java" /> 
</copy>


<copy todir="${warDir}/WEB-INF">
<fileset dir="${deploymentdescription}" includes="web.xml" /> 
</copy>

<copy todir="${warDir}/WEB-INF/lib">
<fileset dir="${jar}" includes="*.jar" /> 
</copy>


<copy todir="${warDir}">
<fileset dir="${web}" includes="**/*.*" /> 
</copy>

<!-- Create war file and place in ear directory -->
<jar jarfile="${earDir}/${warFile}" basedir="${warDir}" />


</target>


<!-- Create the War File -->
<target name="buildEar" depends="init">
<copy todir="${earDir}/META-INF">
<fileset dir="${deploymentdescription}" includes="application.xml" /> 
</copy>

<!-- Create ear file and place in ear directory -->
<jar jarfile="${dirs.base}/${earFile}" basedir="${earDir}" />
</target>

    <target name="clean" description="Delete all generated files">

        <delete dir="${srcDir}" failonerror="false"/>
        <delete dir="${earDir}" failonerror="false"/>
        <delete dir="${warDir}" failonerror="false"/>
        <echo message="Deleted the temp directories src, war, ear"/>
        <mkdir dir="${earDir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${warDir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${srcDir}"/>
        <echo message="created the temp directories src, war, ear"/>

    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: You need to add the missing jars into the "WEB-INF/lib" directory inside your WAR/EAR file. This will automatically add them to the application's classpath at run-time.

Comment: all the jars are already added to the WEB-INF/lib in war. but still i see the runtime classpath issue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't need to add anything to MANIFEST.MF to make your jars added to application classpath.

1. Your web application (WAR) files should be directly under EAR.
2. Overall dependencies (JAR) should be under EAR's APP-INF/lib directory.
3. Web application own dependencies under WAR files WEB-INF/lib directory. Looking at your build.xml, they should be there.

Before changing you Ant build script, please check these prerequisites and please provide the stacktrace from Weblogic error log.